# How to edit my websites source code

Tags: php, html

Hi guys I am sure this question has been asked already but I am a draw me pictures type of person so I need to ask again in my own language. 
I have a website and when I run the W3 Validator on it it says I need to fix some areas of code.

Here is the problem: It is written in .php. All I know is .html.

How can I convert the php source code to html source code so that I can fix what needs to be fixed successfully?

Thank you very much in advance for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: You don't. You need to fix the errors in the PHP code because PHP was presumably used for a reason (interactive website, using a database, et cetera).

Comment: You can't convert PHP Sourcecode to an equivalent HTML Sourcecode. PHP is server side scripting language and html is an markup language.

Comment: Your best bet is to just find a developer to work with and have them do the fixes. If they are mainly layout then you could slice and code the static html/css and then hand it off to them for integration.

Comment: Simeon is right, you can't just convert PHP to HTML.  PHP is a scripting language, HTML is a document format.  It's like asking how to convert an Excel macro to an Excel spreadsheet.  If you post a question with the exact error(s) the W3 Validator is complaining about and a link to your page with the problems, we might be able to help.

Comment: You don't need to know PHP in order to edit a .php file. A .php file can consist of solely HTML.

Comment: PHP is interpreted in server to give HTML. 
Maybe your file contains both HTML tags and some block in php...

Comment: I upvoted it. Newbies need to find answers to basic questions too and there isn't anything wrong with that. I think alot of people on this site take it for granted that everyone is not at an advanced stage of learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your web server is already converting your PHP code to HTML code in order to allow the client web browser to display it. If you have a validation problem, then you have to fix it in your PHP code, otherwise the next time the client requests your web page your validation fix will be overwritten.

So the first things to do is to locate the validation problem across your PHP files. If you're lucky, maybe it's just a bunch of HTML code inside one of your PHP file. Then open your PHP file with a common editor (Vim, Gedit, Eclipse, etc.) and change the code to fix the validation problem.

And then, learn PHP, it will always serve you ;)

Comment: Okay sounds easy enough right? I will give this a shot. It would be so nioce if we could just copy the source code save in html format and then reload it but I guess that would be too easy.

Comment: Take your time, go across your PHP files and once you are comfortable with your project, you will see, it's easy ;)

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. You're awesome!

Comment: You know, your question is quite ridiculous for someone already knowing PHP programming language and website development process that's why you have some downvote for your question. But, these guys have already forgotten that at a given moment not far from today they didn't know anything and had to learn just like you. There is no shame to ask simple questions and it's part of the normal process of learning and increasing your programming skill. That's why I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 2):

PHP executes entirely server-side. Your browser NEVER receives any PHP code (unless there is a big mistake in your server configuration, and it is a security issue).
Use "View source" in your web browser and you'll see what the W3C validator tries to validate.
Then edit your PHP code to generate correct HTML code and make the W3C validator happy.

Comment: wow you make that sound so easy LOL I am going to give it a shot and I hope to god I don't screw this up.